# Android Studio can't create new project

Tags: android, android-studio, runtimeexception

I update Android studio to 2.2.1 but I create a new project I get the RuntimeException.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException:
com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException:
freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template
"root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/recipe.xml.ftl" in line 6,
column 2:Unknown directive: #ifues. Help (latest version):
http://freemarker.org/docs/ref_directive_alphaidx.html; you're using
FreeMarker 2.3.20.
```

Comment: What steps did you take to create the new project?

Comment: file->new -> new project then,next, next, finish(the default step).@Code-Apprentice .sorry I ask question first time.

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, your template file is broken during installation.

Let me attach my file as below. To apply, please do as follows.

1. Close Android Studio.
2. Open your `recipe.xml.ftl` file at `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\android\lib\templates\gradle-projects\NewAndroidModule` directory with text editor (ie, Notepad++)
3. Copy-and-Paste below code, then Save. (`UTF-8` format)
4. Rerun Android Studio.

Note that the file is from Android Studio version **2.2.1**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<recipe>

<#if backwardsCompatibility!true>
    <dependency mavenUrl="com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${buildApi}.+"/>
</#if>

<#if unitTestsSupported>
    <dependency mavenUrl="junit:junit:4.12" gradleConfiguration="testCompile" />
</#if>

<#if !createActivity>
    <mkdir at="${escapeXmlAttribute(srcOut)}" />
</#if>

    <mkdir at="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/libs" />

    <merge from="root/settings.gradle.ftl"
             to="${escapeXmlAttribute(topOut)}/settings.gradle" />
    <instantiate from="root/build.gradle.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/build.gradle" />
    <instantiate from="root/AndroidManifest.xml.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(manifestOut)}/AndroidManifest.xml" />

<mkdir at="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/drawable" />
<#if copyIcons && !isLibraryProject>
    <copy from="root/res/mipmap-hdpi"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/mipmap-hdpi" />
    <copy from="root/res/mipmap-mdpi"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/mipmap-mdpi" />
    <copy from="root/res/mipmap-xhdpi"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/mipmap-xhdpi" />
    <copy from="root/res/mipmap-xxhdpi"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/mipmap-xxhdpi" />
    <copy from="root/res/mipmap-xxxhdpi"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/mipmap-xxxhdpi" />
</#if>
<#if makeIgnore>
    <copy from="root/module_ignore"
            to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/.gitignore" />
</#if>
<#if enableProGuard>
    <instantiate from="root/proguard-rules.txt.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/proguard-rules.pro" />
</#if>
<#if !(isLibraryProject??) || !isLibraryProject>
    <instantiate from="root/res/values/styles.xml.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/values/styles.xml" />
<#if buildApi gte 22>
    <copy from="root/res/values/colors.xml"
          to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/values/colors.xml" />
</#if>
</#if>

    <instantiate from="root/res/values/strings.xml.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(resOut)}/values/strings.xml" />

    <instantiate from="root/test/app_package/ExampleInstrumentedTest.java.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(testOut)}/ExampleInstrumentedTest.java" />

<#if unitTestsSupported>
    <instantiate from="root/test/app_package/ExampleUnitTest.java.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(unitTestOut)}/ExampleUnitTest.java" />
</#if>
<#if includeCppSupport!false>
    <instantiate from="root/CMakeLists.txt.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(projectOut)}/CMakeLists.txt" />

    <mkdir at="${nativeSrcOut}" />
    <instantiate from="root/native-lib.cpp.ftl" to="${nativeSrcOut}/native-lib.cpp" />
</#if>

</recipe>
```

Comment: Thank you.It takes effect.But it show another Exception that means ApplicationTest.java.ftl not found,whereupon i annotation

Comment: I annotate                                                                                              <instantiate from="root/test/app_package/ApplicationTest.java.ftl"
                   to="${escapeXmlAttribute(testOut)}/ApplicationTest.java" />    in the file you offered and it compiles successfully

Comment: @why_rookie // I recommend you to uninstall AndroidStudio, remove `C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio` folder, and reinstall. It should not be happened in general, so some other files might be broken also.

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation, there are no exceptions for now.I'll try it later when the current project is finished.