# I can't create new project on my android studio 2.2 for mac

Tags: android, android-studio

just as usual,step by step,[image]

[image]

[image]
then,android studio dismissed,
Strangely,other projects is fine,

there is the error info,can anyone help me?

> Blockquote
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/recipe.xml.ftl" in line 6, column 2:
>   Unknown directive: #ifsOut. Directive names are all-lower-case.
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/recipe.xml.ftl" in line 6, column 2:
>   Unknown directive: #ifsOut. Directive names are all-lower-case.
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator.invokeAndWait(LaterInvocator.java:179)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.invokeAndWait(ApplicationImpl.java:731)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:82)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.runWriteCommandAction(Template.java:278)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:238)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.npw.deprecated.NewFormFactorModulePath.performFinishingOperation(NewFormFactorModulePath.java:309)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.npw.deprecated.NewFormFactorModulePath.canPerformFinishingActions(NewFormFactorModulePath.java:264)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.doFinish(DynamicWizard.java:649)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.npw.NewProjectWizardDynamic.doFinish(NewProjectWizardDynamic.java:275)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard$1.run(DynamicWizard.java:422)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:227)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:563)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$8.run(CoreProgressManager.java:357)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$2.run(CoreProgressManager.java:142)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:446)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:392)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:127)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$13$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:633)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:369)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/recipe.xml.ftl" in line 6, column 2:
>   Unknown directive: #ifsOut. Directive names are all-lower-case.
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.doRender(Template.java:330)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$000(Template.java:66)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1$1.compute(Template.java:248)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1$1.compute(Template.java:245)
>       at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PostprocessReformattingAspect.disablePostprocessFormattingInside(PostprocessReformattingAspect.java:124)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1.compute(Template.java:245)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1.compute(Template.java:238)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$2.run(Template.java:276)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:35)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:108)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:103)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.access$000(WriteCommandAction.java:34)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:85)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$1.run(LaterInvocator.java:160)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.runNextEvent(LaterInvocator.java:345)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.LaterInvocator$FlushQueue.run(LaterInvocator.java:329)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.pumpEventsForHierarchy(IdeEventQueue.java:944)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:210)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.util.ProgressWindow.startBlocking(ProgressWindow.java:197)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ApplicationImpl.java:649)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:354)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(ProgressManagerImpl.java:76)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcessWithProgressSynchronously(CoreProgressManager.java:230)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.doFinishAction(DynamicWizard.java:417)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DialogWrapperHost$FinishAction.doAction(DialogWrapperHost.java:365)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1811)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>       at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>       at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>       at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>       at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>       at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>       at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>       at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>       at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:654)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
>       at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:792)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:465)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.invokeShow(DialogWrapper.java:1661)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1610)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.dynamic.DynamicWizard.show(DynamicWizard.java:497)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:64)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:191)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:312)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:958)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:282)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>       at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:110)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>       at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>       at javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:308)
>       at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
>       at com.apple.laf.ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.itemStateChanged(ScreenMenuItemCheckbox.java:193)
>       at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processItemEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:389)
>       at java.awt.CheckboxMenuItem.processEvent(CheckboxMenuItem.java:357)
>       at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEventImpl(MenuComponent.java:351)
>       at java.awt.MenuComponent.dispatchEvent(MenuComponent.java:339)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:761)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:857)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:658)
>       at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:386)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
>   Caused by: com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils$TemplateProcessingException: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/recipe.xml.ftl" in line 6, column 2:
>   Unknown directive: #ifsOut. Directive names are all-lower-case.
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils.processFreemarkerTemplate(FreemarkerUtils.java:111)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.executeRecipeFile(Template.java:478)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$300(Template.java:66)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$4.startElement(Template.java:440)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processXml(Template.java:405)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processFile(Template.java:389)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.doRender(Template.java:296)
>       ... 123 more
>   Caused by: freemarker.core.ParseException: Parsing error in template "root://gradle-projects/NewAndroidModule/recipe.xml.ftl" in line 6, column 2:
>   Unknown directive: #ifsOut. Directive names are all-lower-case.
>       at freemarker.core.TokenMgrError.toParseException(TokenMgrError.java:233)
>       at freemarker.template.Template.(Template.java:199)
>       at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.loadTemplate(TemplateCache.java:419)
>       at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:330)
>       at freemarker.cache.TemplateCache.getTemplate(TemplateCache.java:205)
>       at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:740)
>       at freemarker.template.Configuration.getTemplate(Configuration.java:665)
>       at com.android.tools.idea.templates.FreemarkerUtils.processFreemarkerTemplate(FreemarkerUtils.java:91)
>       ... 140 more

Answer (score 0):

Java Runtime Exception: Unknow directive - Directive names are all-lower-case.
Maybe here you will find some valuable information: [Android Studio can't create new project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40098564/android-studio-cant-create-new-project)

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation,it helps me to solve the problem.